# How do I format a row within subtotal on matrix?

Tags: reporting-services, matrix

I have a dataset that I need to report as a matrix. Within the dataset, I pull together the individual totals for CDNs within a week, along with the overall total for all CDNs within the week. I do this to make it easy to calculate the weekly percentages within the report.

I am using Visual Studio 2005 to build the report. You can see the matrix definition on Sheet2.

Everything works out fine until i get to the bottom Total. As you can see on Sheet3, the total Offered is correct, but the % to Total is not correct. In fact, i do not even need this row visible on the Total section. How can i hide this row?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possible ways to **hide** the rows or row values in sub-totals section of SSRS reports. The examples shown below use **`SSRS 2005`**.

**A**. First option is to set the `Initial Visibility` Expression on the cells to hide the rows. Totals label cell will span to two rows, which might not look good. Refer screenshot #**1**.

**B**. Second option is to display the data in the cells based on the scope. This will not hide the row but won't show any data. Refer screenshot #**7**.

Following sections explain how each of the above options can be achieved.

**Using Option A:**

1. Right-click on the cell that has `Phonenumber` and `CDN source` expression and select Edit Group... as shown in screenshot #**2**.
2. Make note of the **Name**. Here, this example uses the name `PhoneNumber`. Click `OK` or `Cancel`. Refer screemshot #**3**.
3. Right-click on the cell containing the text `% to Total` and select `Properties` as shown in screenshot #**4**.
4. On the `Textbox Properties` dialog, click on the `Visibility` tab and select `Expression` radio button. In the Expression, enter the value **`=Not(InScope("PhoneNumber"))`**. Refer screenshot #**5**.
5. Right-click on the cell containing the expression to calculate the % to Totals value and select `Properties` as shown in screenshot #**6**. Repeat the step **6** for this cell as well.

**Using Option B:**

6. Perform steps 1 & 2 mentioned in previous option **A**.
7. Right-click on the cell containing the text `% to Total` and select `Expression` as shown in screenshot #**8**.
8. Change the expression to `=IIf(InScope("PhoneNumber"), "% to Total", Nothing)`
9. Right-click on the cell containing the expression to calculate the % to Totals value and select `Expression` as shown in screenshot #**9**.
10. Change the expression to `=IIf(InScope("PhoneNumber"), Round((IIf(Sum(Fields!Offered.Value) = 0 Or Sum(Fields!WeekTotal.Value) = 0, 0, Sum(Fields!Offered.Value)/Sum(Fields!WeekTotal.Value))) * 100, 1).ToString() + " %", Nothing)`
11. Make sure that you change the expressions according to your requirements.

Output of option **A** can be seen in screenshot #**1** and output of option **B** can be seen in screenshot #**7**.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

Comment: WOW! Thank you for the very thorough answer. I knew there had to be a way to do this using InScope, but i just could not figure out the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out another way to do this. Because of how my data is set up, the WkTotOff.Value in the SubTotal section is always going to be a factor of the number of CDN_Values there are. Therefore, i could place
=iif(Sum(Fields!WkTotOff.Value)/CountDistinct(Fields!CDN_Val.Value) = Sum(Fields!Offered.Value), "Silver", "White") in the Background Color in the properties of the row i want to hide (in the detail section). Since the individual detail level will never meet this criteria, these will remain visible.

This seems a bit sloppy but was all i could figure out.  I will try your methods as well.

PK